# Separate structure subpanel electrode grounding - Rod count and separation requirements

Tags: electrical, grounding, subpanel

Having a subpanel replaced in garage (60 amp). No prior electrode grounding exists, which needs to be added.  Most information I've come across cites use of 2 electrodes, minimally spaced 6 feet apart (per NEC refernces)  A local expert cited use of 4 rods, in a 3x3 foot square configuration.  Is this realistic or advisable? Asking because I've discovered no other references to the latter (3x3) configuration.

Comment: I've never heard of using 4, but I know soil conditions can affect conductivity.  For example, very rocky subsoil will not be as conductive, whereas a deep topsoil/clay will be more conductive.  Maybe your local soil conditions dictate that and require more ground rods, or the contractor is trying to upsell you.

Answer (score 1):

4 rods in a 3x3 foot square would not meet NEC requirements<sup>*</sup>, and is an odd approach. Your local "expert" is skating on questionable "expertise."

<sup>*</sup>NEC permits as little as one rod *if* you do a ground resistance measurement (and get a value under 25 ohms) that typically costs more to do than simply installing two rods, adequately spaced. Wasting 4 rods in a too-tight configuration would require doing the expensive measurement, when you could just space the 4 rods adequately and do more than code **minimum.** You can always *exceed* code, you can't do *less* than it requires.

The 6 foot *minimum* ground rod spacing can (or even should) be exceeded. The use of two rods can be exceeded. But the minimum (unless you want to run the pricy measurement, **and** the result of it is good) is 2 8 foot rods at least 6 feet apart.

If you really want the finest of ground electrodes, pour some concrete, with well-tied reenforcing steel, and provide a place to connect to the steel for a "concrete encased electrode" - they are practically free any time you properly plan a concrete pour that accommodates 20 feet or more of reenforcing steel. But that's unlikely when retrofitting, rather than building, a garage.